# VSCode API check if path exists

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In a VSCode extension, how can I check if a file path exists without opening or reading the file?

The closest thing I've found are `vscode.workspace.fs.Readfile` and `vscode.workspace.openTextDocument` (https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#FileSystem), but again, I do not want to open or read the file. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no API for that because there is a builtin function:

```
import * as fs from 'fs'; // In NodeJS: 'const fs = require('fs')'
if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
  // File exists in path
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is still the case. See new vscode fs API notes [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_vscodeworkspacefs)

Comment: Doesn't follow recommendations for Virtual Workspaces.

Answer (score 11):

Per @realappie's comment on another answer, you can use [`vscode.workspace.fs`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_37#_vscodeworkspacefs).

It doesn't have a method like `exists`, but you can use `.stat()` for that. An example from [the repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-extension-samples/blob/0b3a31bf2bdd388ac4fdc0ccea2fb1315abfe3e3/fsconsumer-sample/src/extension.ts#L27-L32):

```
try {
    await vscode.workspace.fs.stat(jsUri);
    vscode.window.showTextDocument(jsUri, { viewColumn: vscode.ViewColumn.Beside });
} catch {
    vscode.window.showInformationMessage(`${jsUri.toString(true)} file does *not* exist`);
}
```